# Symfony2 Forms Generated with CRUD - Can I automatically use Sonata Admin with the existing forms?

Tags: symfony, crud, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I have forms generated with `generate:doctrine:crud`, they work perfectly, but do not look very nice.
While looking for something different I found Sonata Admin module.

It is really cool with different features, buttons and a very nice layout.

My question is, how can I apply it to my existing forms?
Can they be created automatically just as `generate:doctrine:crud` does?

What I understood is that I must create all the forms again, manually using Sonata Methods.

Answer (score 1):

Soanata Admin is backoffice generator. It's useful to fastly create administration pages and as you said, it uses its own system of Form generation.

What you like in Sonata design is the use of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) that is a frontend framework (CSS+JavaScript). You can use it in your own project, without using Sonata.

By overriding native Symfony form rendering with Bootstrap `controls` elements, you will render nice looking forms too !